# jQuery Mobile responsive thumbnail in listview

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

Simply put, I want to have the thumbnails in a JQM listview hide when the device is not wide enough to support them.  I can technically accomplish that, but the space is not being re-used (which is the whole point of hiding them).

My CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 30em) {
    .list-breakpoint img { display: none; }
}
```

And an element of the list:

```
<li class="list-breakpoint" data-theme='a'>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="..." class="ui-li-thumb">
        <p><b>Title</b><br/>
           Line 1<br/>
           Line 2</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: display: none; takes the thumbs out of view and reclaims space unlike visibility: hidden; . if you are saying that it doesnt then perhaps some other class is using that space. Inspect an Item on a browser and see what css is been used after the display: none; is run in the breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor tag button in the LI has extra padding on the left to make room for the image, so as well as hiding the image, adjust the padding:

```
@media all and (max-width: 30em) {
    .list-breakpoint img { display: none; }
    .list-breakpoint a.ui-btn { padding-left: 1em !important; }
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/oLVKBp)**